# XCode 4, Armadillo and the XCode standard library

Tags: c++, xcode4, armadillo, std

I'm attempting to compile my (very basic) program that uses armadillo in XCode 4, but it is having problems with compiling armadillo.

When I do just a simple makefile and clang++, it compiles without problems, but using XCode it seems to be having serious issues, popping up with all kinds of errors and warnings, (when I build it without XCode, even using -Werrors, I get nothing, it builds clean).

Here are some of there errors:

```
const int __ret = std::vsnprintf(__out, __size, __fmt, __args); <-- no member named vsnprintf in namespace std (in file c++locale.h)

return (std::isfinite(x) != 0); <-- Expected unqualified-id (in file cmath_wrap.hpp)
```

etc.  I think most of them are related to some function not in the standard library... does XCode use a different or incomplete standard library?  And how do I change that.

I really just want to use the XCode debugger, it makes things easier when my code isn't running, and it is nice to have a graphical profiler as well.

Comment: no, I think I gave up and moved on... sorry :(

Answer (score 7):

Try uncheck option "recursive" in your "Build Setting/Header Search Path"